# Removing array key from multidimensional Arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
 $cart= Array(
      [0] => Array([id] => 15[price] => 400)
      [1] => Array([id] => 12[price] => 400)
    )
```

What i need is to remove array key based on some value, like this

```
$value = 15;
```

Value is 15 is just example i need to check array and remove if that value exist in ID?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a lot of weird array functions in PHP, but many of these requests are solved with very simple foreach loops...

```
$value = 15;
foreach ($cart as $i => $v) {
    if ($v['id'] == $value) {
        unset($cart[$i]);
    }
}
```

If $value is not in the array at all, nothing will happen. If $value is in the array, the entire index will be deleted (unset).

Comment: If replacing $a with $cart was confusing, this may be over your head.

Answer (score 15):

[`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is great for removing things you don't want from arrays.

```
$cart = array_filter($cart, function($x) { return $x['id'] != 15; });
```

If you want to use a variable to determine which id to remove rather than including it in the `array_filter` callback, you can `use` your variable in the function like this:

```
$value = 15;
$cart = array_filter($cart, function($x) use ($value) { return $x['id'] != $value; });
```

Comment: This answer should accepted.. No one wants to use loop for a single task

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
foreach($array as $key => $item) {
  if ($item['id'] === $value) {
    unset($array[$key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't do that by reference because I know I will use $item later and it will take me hours to realize that $item is a reference to the last item in $array.

Comment: This cannot work, because `unset($item)` does not remove the array element; it only unsets the reference to it.

Comment: if you create `function clearArray($value){ ... }` you not need more use $item later, btw I think better solution to up with `array_filter` function from php